# Parameter integrals - show continuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration

One little question concerning the proof of

> > Let $I=[a,b], D=[c,d]$ compact ranges and $f\in C^0(I\times D)$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Then
> >     $$
> > F(t):=\int_a^b f(x,t)\, dx
> > $$
> >     is continious for all $t\in D$.

Proof: $I\times D$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore $f$ is uniformly continious on $I\times D$, that means:

For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta >0$ in such a way that
$$
\lvert f(x_1,t_1)-f(x_2,t_2)\rvert\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}
$$
for all $(x_i,t_i)\in I\times D$ with $\lvert (x_1,t_1)-x_2,t_2)\rvert\leq\delta$.

My question is: Where does the denominator $(b-a)$ come from? I cannot explain the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
&|F(t_1) - F(t_2)| \\
&= |\int_a^b f(x,t_1) dx - \int_a^b f(x,t_2) dx |\\
&\leq \int_a^b|f(x,t_1)  - f(x,t_2)| dx\\
\end{split}
\end{gather}
If $|f(x,t_1)  - f(x,t_2)| < \epsilon $, then $|F(t_1) - F(t_2)| < \epsilon (b-a)$.
So if we want to show $|F(t_1) - F(t_2)| < \epsilon $ we should take $|f(x,t_1)  - f(x,t_2)| < \epsilon (b-a) $\
So the denominator $b-a$ comes.